# How to check if droppable area is empty during submitting form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have form with droppable area:

```
<form>
    <span id="error">
    <!----Initializing Session for errors--->
        <?php
            if (!empty($_SESSION['error1'])) {
                echo $_SESSION['error1'];
                unset($_SESSION['error1']);
            }
        ?>
    </span> 
    <div class="projLeader">
    <ol>
        <li class="placeholder" name="projLeader" <?php if (isset($projLeader)) echo 'value="'.$projLeader.'"' ?>><div class="adding">Drop here</div></li>
        <input type="hidden" name="projLeader" class="hiddenListInput1" required/>
    </ol>
    <input type = "submit" name ="submit" class="button" value = "Create Report" onclick="userSubmitted = true;"/>
    </div>    
</form>
```

Where placeholder "Drop here" will be removed once item is dropped. And I am saving dropped data by this js function:

```
var LISTOBJ1 = {
  saveList: function() {
    var listCSV = "";
    $( ".projLeader li" ).each(function() {
      if (listCSV === "") {
        listCSV = $(this).text();
      } else {
        listCSV += "," + $(this).text();
      }
      $(".hiddenListInput1").val(listCSV);
    });
  }
}
```

So my question is how i can make validation and not allow user to submit empty field, or field with "Drop here" placeholder, because if user adds nothing and just presses submit i got it placeholder to print.
I tried to check if it is empty by posting data and checking if it is empty:

```
$projLeader=$_POST['procLeader'];
if (empty($projLeader))
{
  //setting error message
  $_SESSION['error1'] = "Mandatory field(s) are missing, Please fill it again";
  header("location: createProject2.php"); //redirecting to first page           
}
```

So what is the way to make a validation? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When no item has `dropped` in `droppable` area then your `hidden` field will have `"Drop here"` value. So your `condition` should check for either hidden field have `no value` or hidden field have `"Drop here"` value and it should consider `blank`.

**Note:** Your spell was also wrong for getting value of hidden field. It must be `projLeader` not `procLeader`.

Please try with below modified PHP code.

```
$projLeader=trim($_POST['projLeader']);
if (empty($projLeader) || $projLeader == "Drop here")
{
    //setting error message
    $_SESSION['error1'] = "Mandatory field(s) are missing, Please fill it again";
    header("location: createProject2.php"); //redirecting to first page         
}
```

And must have to place `sesstion_start();` function on both the pages to use `$_SESSION`.